# Add intellij to environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, paths, intellij

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my system.
I downloaded Intellij and CLion using Ubuntu Software. In order to open it from terminal I used the command `export PATH=$PATH:./clion.sh` this command worked for CLion. However, it didn't work for IntelliJ when I typed the command `PATH=$PATH:./idea.sh`

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:./clion.sh` adds the file `clion.sh` in the directory you are in to the search path (the places that are looked in for the right files when you type in a command). . 
- Does idea.sh exist?
- Also consider giving absolute paths, since I assume you don't want to depend on being in the right directory to open your IDE.